# Turn or switch a car's ignition?

Tags: verbs

A vehicle's ignition works with a switch. But when describing the action of activating the ignition but not engaging the starter, which is more correct: "Turn on the ignition" (because we traditionally turn a key to achieve this) or "Switch on the ignition" (because it is operated by means of an electric switch)?

Comment: Both are good. I couldn't say which is more usual (in BrE).

Comment: When you apply power to an ordinary lamp you "turn on" the light.

Comment: @HotLicks: but "switch on" is also current for that. I have even encountered "open the light," which struck me as odd in that the action in question involves *closing* the electrical circuit. So varied usage is current here--just do not direct or invite your chauffeur to *ignite* the vehicle :)

Comment: @BrianDonovan I've (UK)  only heard open/close from people born before about 1930, at least in this sense opposite to circuitry. I'd always assumed it went back to gas lighting.

Comment: AmE, southern -- I'm accustomed to hearing simply "turn the ignition" (without "on"). For example, "Nothing happens when I turn the ignition."

Comment: @pyobum Opposite here. My immediate reaction to the title was, “The answer is neither: you turn or switch _on_ the ignition; you don’t turn it, and you certain don’t switch it”. I guess ignitional prepositions are dialectal—but I am right to assume, am I not, that even in the South, you wouldn’t say “switch the ignition”?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I suspect it's dialectal as well, and perhaps it also depends on SES...? And yes, I'd say you're right to assume. I can't recall ever hearing someone say "switch the ignition." There is "cut [various electronics/electrical devices] on," which was addressed [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118997/cut-the-lights-on), with the OP remarking at the illogicity of "cutting lights on." I can't say for certain I've ever heard "cut the ignition on," but I wouldn't be *surprised* to hear it in colloquial Southern speech, especially among the blue-collar rural crowd.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet And just because I've yet to see it on this site, I'm gonna post a nice little collection of dialect survey maps (sadly, nothing ignition-related): http://dialect.redlog.net/

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is "turn the ignition switch to the 'on' position."

Here's an explanation from https://www.yourmechanic.com/question/what-are-the-ignition-switch-positions

If your car is equipped with a standard ignition and a mechanical key/remote combination, you have several different ignition switch positions that you’ll need to know (smart key systems have one less ignition switch position). Here’s an overview of each ignition position:

```
Lock: This is the off position. No accessories work, and you can take the key out of the ignition. The steering wheel can also be locked.

Accessory: In accessory mode, you can listen to the radio, as well as use some other electronics. The key cannot be removed from the ignition.

On: This turns on all of your electronics. The key cannot be removed. The key will also default to this position after you crank the engine.

Start: Turn the key to this position to crank the engine. Let go of the key as soon as the engine starts. Holding the key in start after the engine is running can damage the starter.
```

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, use neither. When you're talking about the ignition itself, you're more likely to sound natural if you use "start the igniton" instead. On the other hand, when you're talking about the key, either one of "turn on the ignition key" and "switch on the ignition key" would suffice.

Comment: Thanks for this, Aura. However, "start the ignition" does not work here because I am trying to describe the process of turning the key to activate the ignition without actually starting the engine. Your phrase implies an engine start without distinguishing between two possible "states" of the ignition, if that makes any sense.

Comment: I would never "start the ignition".  I would "start the car" or "start the engine", but I would "turn on the ignition", if I were not going to start the car in the next instant.

Comment: @DeondeLange, if that is what you mean, please so specify in your question, not just a comment. And if you are simply switching on the car's electrical systems thus, you are not even using the typically keyed switch for the function that gives it its usual name as the ignition switch--which function is the sparking of explosive combustion within one or more cylinders.

Comment: Apologies, @BrianDonovan. First time user. Still finding my way.

Comment: Generic *turn the key, turn on the ignition, switch on the ignition* would normally be understood to mean start the engine. Since you specifically don't want this, but want to indicate switching to *run* without bumping the momentary start position, I'd use very explicit and redundant language to get the point across (at least the first time). "Turn the key one position from *off* to *run* without engaging the starter. This engages the ignition system."

Comment: @PhilSweet I've often heard and used "turn on the *ignition*" as meaning enough clicks to switch the accessories on but not to "turn on the *engine*". This may be strictly accessory mode, or it may be the engine running position but without running the starter.

Comment: When virtually everyone uses "turn on the ignition", this answer is absurd.

Comment: @Deon For your particular scenario, I would say “turn the key in the ignition”. This implies turning the key without turning on the engine.